# How to the reflection of a point about a line?

Tags: coordinate-systems, reflection

I've been doing some problems on the topic `Reflection`.And struggling with it when I am doing it graphically. I have solved it using `Reflection Matrix` but graphically it is giving the wrong answer. Please enlighten me where I am wrong?

I solved it for the equation `Y = X` correctly like

> I have to find the reflection of the point `(2,5)` about `Y = X`, whose answer will definitely be `(5,2)`
>
> > > HOW I DID IT.
> >
> > First of All I find the corresponding point on the line `Y = x`, which will be  `(5,5) and (2,2)`, and the corresponding reflected point will have the same value of x coordinate as (5,5) and same value of Y coordinate as (2,2) so the answer will be `(5,2)` which is correct.

*I am attaching an image in my support*[image: First Problem]

But when I solve it for equation `2Y = X + 1` it gives me wrong result

> I have to find the reflection of the point `(3,-3)` about `2Y = X + 1`, whose answer is (-1,5) but my answer is `(7,2)`
>
> > > HOW I DID IT.
> >
> > First of All I find the corresponding point on the line `2Y = X + 1`, which will be  `(3,2) and (-7,-3)`, and the corresponding reflected point will have the same value of x coordinate as (-7,-3) and same value of Y coordinate as (3,2) so the answer will be `(-7,2)` which is incorrect.

*attached an image in my support*[image: Second Problem]

Please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Any other requirements or doubt in question?
Please ask me in comments.

Comment: I would compute the perpendicular line to the given line.

Comment: oh, you mean a line passing from those points and is perpendicular to the given line? Nice idea. but where am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean, i think that is a better method to find the searched Points.

Comment: Definately thats the better way. but where is my mistake in the method that i followed?

Comment: The line $$y=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}$$ divides not the angle $$90^{\circ}$$ into equal parts like $y=x$

Comment: Apologies, I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your construction uses that the angle of the coordinate axes will divide into equal parts, $$45^{\circ}$$

Comment: Got it, thankyou.

Comment: Is your Problem solved now?